# Executar update de pesquisa no botão

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsp

Meu campo de busca atualiza um selectManyMenu sempre que algo é digitado nele

```
<p:inputText id="txtFiltroOrgaoDestino" value="#{mBManifestacao.txtFiltroOrgaoDestino}" style="width: 350px">
    <p:ajax update="slcUnidadeTramite" event="keyup" global="false" listener="#{mBManifestacao.filtrarOrgaoDestino}" />
</p:inputText>
```

Porém quando o campo é liberado para edição ele já vem com um texto nele, e gostaria que nesse momento ele filtrasse, pois og necessito ir no campo selecionar e dar um espaço por exemplo

Tentei de tudo que é jeito que pude imaginar fazer o botão que libera pra edição executar um update no campo, mas sem sucesso

```
<p:commandButton
    update=":frmAdministrarManifestacao,
            :frmEncaminharManifestacao,
            :frmTramiteManifestacao"
    process="@this, btnAnalisarManifestacao"
    value="Analisar Manifestação" id="btnAnalisarManifestacao"
    action="#{mBManifestacao.gravaStatusManifestacao()}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        value="#{mBEnum.codStatusManifestacaoEM_ANALISE}"
        target="#{mBManifestacao.manifestacao.stStatusManifestacao}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

**Atualização:**

Consegui, após muito tentar, melhorar um pouco a situação sendo que não preciso mais dar o espaço, apenas ao selecionar o campo ele já executa o filtro agora:

```
<p:inputText id="txtFiltroOrgaoDestino" value="#{mBManifestacao.txtFiltroOrgaoDestino}" style="width: 350px">
    <p:ajax update="slcUnidadeTramite" event="click" global="false" listener="#{mBManifestacao.filtrarOrgaoDestino}" />
    <p:ajax update="slcUnidadeTramite" event="keyup" global="false" listener="#{mBManifestacao.filtrarOrgaoDestino}" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: Você está setando a variável #{mBManifestacao.txtFiltroOrgaoDestino} para vazio no método #{mBManifestacao.gravaStatusManifestacao()}?

Comment: Não é justamente ali que atribuo o texto que quero que ele comece

Comment: Não sei se me expliquei direito mas não quero limpar o campo e sim executar a filtragem do selectManyMenu

Comment: Entendi. Então porque você não filtra o resultado dentro do método #{mBManifestacao.gravaStatusManifestacao()} e atualiza o componente alvo? Não precisa esperar o valor chegar até o input para filtrar. Filtra pelo bean antes.

Comment: Verdade, estava tão focado em fazer no botão mesmo que nem pensei em fazer no bean, vou tentar aqui, obrigado

Comment: Muito obrigado @Bonifacio chamei a função filtrarOrgaoDestino() após setar o conteúdo e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Excelente @Mateus! JSF deveria possibilitar atribuir o mesmo comportamento a múltiplos eventos do ajax sem precisar criar múltiplas tags, mas pelo menos o problema foi resolvido.